# Font should not be stretched while doing ScaleTransform.ScaleY

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using the following code to increase the Button height 50% dynamically.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
             <Setter.Value/>
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1.5" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
             </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

But i think LayoutTransform changes the font height also. As I am only increasing the height (ScaleY), the font of the buttons looks liks stretched Vertically.

But I dont want to increase the font size when do the ScaleTransform. Instead i want to change the font size manually and also it should not look like stretched.

Please help me how to do this??? It will be really helpful if i get any code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your XAML, it is hard to answer exactly, but here are a few ideas ...

I am guessing you can't just set the Button height for whatever reason.

So you want the button to be 1.5 times higher, but you do not want to scale its contents? If this is the case, can you place it within a container, a Grid for example, then apply the LayoutTransform to the Grid?

Or, you could apply yor LayoutTransform to the button, then apply a RenderTransform to its contents that would 'cancel ou' this 1.5 times scaling.

Comment: My XAML code is only that much in my App.xaml. So it will increase all my button height 50% more based on some condition. As this is generalized code I will go for your sencond option... Can you please give a small code sample?